# DotNetNuke Unit Testing Facilities and Tutorials

Tags: dotnetnuke

What is the standard, best practice way to perform unit testing in a dotnetnuke app?  I have searched SO as well as the dnn website, and wasn't able to find much info about this.  I assume dnn has something baked in for doing unit tests, or at the very least a library that can be plugged in.  Where can I find more info?  A tutorial on the subject would be ideal, but any resource at all would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't much information on testing within DotNetNuke.  Being a WebForms based project, it hasn't been a strong concern of many of the developers in the community.

For examples, you can look at the unit testing projects within DNN's source, which have a number of different approaches used.  They use MbUnit and Moq for unit testing, as well as Watin for testing the web frontent.

The main technique for making testable modules is to use the WebForms MVP integration, so that you have testable, loosely-coupled presenters that you can inject dependencies into easily.  There's the start of a [sample module on codeplex](http://testdrivendnnmodule.codeplex.com/), but it's never been fully fleshed out.  However, it does has some good background on its project page.

Comment: bdukes, thanks for replying.  as i come from a ruby and php background, i have newb .NET question about your answer.  when you say WebForms MVP integration is the main technique for making testable modules, do you mean that you write your unit tests using MVP, and then plug your now-tested MVP component into DNN?  or did you mean something else entirely?

Comment: WebForms MVP is a framework for developing your module.  The framework enables separation that is difficult to achieve with the standard WebForms development methods. You can use whatever testing framework you want ([NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/), [xUnit.net](http://xunit.codeplex.com/), [MbUnit](http://mbunit.com/), [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/)), as well as any mocking/isolation framework ([Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq), [FakeItEasy](https://github.com/patrik-hagne/FakeItEasy), [RhinoMocks](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-mocks), [TypeMock](http://www.typemock.com/))

Answer (score 2):

For a data-driven unit testing approach, be aware of following:

- Create app.config file for unit test project and copy sections related to "data", "caching" from web.config of DNN web app
- Install caching provider before running any tests:
  `ComponentFactory.InstallComponents(New ProviderInstaller("caching", GetType(CachingProvider)))`

Answer (score 1):

When unit testing data driven modules:

- Be sure to add core DNN files + DotNetNuke.Instrumentation.dll + PetaPoco if needeed
- Include data & caching sections in app.config (copy sections from DNN web.config)
- initialize data & caching providers in your code before invoking DataProvider methods:

  ComponentFactory.InstallComponents(new ProviderInstaller("data", typeof(DataProvider)), new ProviderInstaller("caching", typeof(CachingProvider)));

Comment: Add a ComponentFactory.Container = new SimpleContainer(); before InstallComponents and all is ok